# Speed up reading frames from a video file

Tags: c++, opencv, video

Is there any way with OpenCV to read frames from a video file in parallel or speed up reading in some other way?

I have tried using the `cap.read(frame)` function in multiple threads, but application crashes.

I also tried with `VideoCapture` object array `cap`s, all referencing the same video file, then in each thread I can use `caps[i].read(frame)` and so I can read in parallel, but I just read the same frame multiple times.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Are you processing the frames at all? Have you tried putting the video on a SSD or RAMdrive?

Comment: Hi @Mark Setchell. I am implementing a custom C++ video player application that need to be able to run a “special” very big video file at 30FPS and I don’t need to process the frames. As you mentioned, one solution would be to pre-process video file and then use memory mapping but because of the video size that is not an option. I have also tried to read the video file with FFmpeg but it is slower than OpenCV.
There is much material on the internet regarding image processing acceleration techniques but I haven’t found anything regarding reading the video file.

Comment: "custom video player"..."don’t need to process the frames" -- then OpenCV is a poor choice. `VideoCapture` is a convenience tool for prototyping.

Comment: Hi @DanMašek. What would be a better choice?

Comment: I'm curious regarding the statement `"...tried to read the video file with FFmpeg but it is slower than OpenCV"`.  Doesn't `OpenCV` use the various `ffmpeg` libraries itself?

Comment: @G.M. that is an excellent question and I don’t know the answer :). I just measured the times needed to read a frame and with OpenCV it is around 30-35ms and with ffmpeg it is around 60-65ms. I must admit I haven’t played much with different settings here I just continued with OpenCV. Do you have different experiences or suggestions?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/50910945/13552470

Comment: @AnnZen This is a really nice example, but if I understand it correctly, it shows how to speed up the processing of the video frames, not how to speed up the reading of the video.

Comment: @ervoL Oh, okay.

Comment: It's very hard to assist with such a vague question. You seem to want to read a *"special"* video (whatever that is) very fast for some reason without wanting to process it or even mentioning displaying it - not sure why you'd want to do that. You say it is *"very big"* without saying whether that means the frames are 48,000x72,000 pixels in size or that there are 346 million of them? You give no indication of your OS, nor the pixel format or container of the video, or whether you have fast disk or lots of RAM. You show no sample code, nor do you give any timings for what you have measured...

Comment: Hi @MarkSetchell ! The video is special because it is used as a test video used in our labs and any change to it requires a long verification process, which should be avoided if possible. After reading the frame, it is sent to a Blackmagic video player device (UltraStudio Mini). The video itself is in Apple ProRes H422 format with a resolution of 3840 x 2160 pixels. It is about 240GB in size and after conversion to a raw byte file it is about 2TB, so it is not suitable for memory mapping. Computer runs on MacOS and it has 1TB SSD and 16GB RAM. Timings I mentioned in a comment above.

Comment: Ok, so are you displaying it or not. If you are displaying it, presumably at 30fps, are you saying you cannot read a frame every 33ms which is what you would need to keep up with displaying it? If so, how long does it take to read a frame?

Comment: Hi @MarkSetchell ! I am not displaying the frames directly, I am sending them to the Blackmagic player and it is in charge for displaying it but still it is my responsibility to send the frames correctly. Video is running 30fps so, as you said, I have 33ms time window but I need around 40ms (30-35ms to read a frame + 5-7ms to convert it BGR->BGRA).

Comment: Ok, thank you for the update. Note that all the details in your comments should really be in your question so future readers can find them without wading through unformatted comments. Please now click `edit` under your question and insert your code so we can actually see if there are some optimisations we can suggest. Thank you.

Comment: While you are adding your code to your question, please also add the output from `ffprobe YOURVIDEO` Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found any other way to speed up the reading other than changing the video format. I changed it to HapQ (original format was Apple ProRes H422) and the performance was noticeably better, about 30% faster (20-25 ms for reading frames compared to 30-35 ms before).

Comment: That was always likely to be the outcome when you didn't share enough information for anyone to help.